# <slot> functionality in angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular, vue.js

I am working with SPA (single page application) , I have used Vue framework to develop the application.

- Front-End : Vue
- Back-End : NodeJs

In my application I have other sub-modules written in angular 4, I want to write the functionality provided by Vue in angular.
[Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) is the link which can explain the `<slot>` functionality.

Can anyone suggest solution to implement the same in Angular4 onwards?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's called transclusion, and is implemented with `ng-content` through Angular.

See some tutorials online, such as https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content

This allows you to create components like this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `<div class="container"><ng-content></ng-content></div>`
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

In your HTML :

```
<app-component>Some text</app-component>
```

Will be rendered as :

```
<div class="container">Some text</div>
```

Even you can have named `ng-content` too. if you have multiple contents to be replaced. for example -

```
<ng-content select="[card-body]"></ng-content>
```

Comment: (PS : I know this should be a comment, by it allows the OP to close his question)

Comment: Just make it answer-worthy by adding a code example.

Comment: @Marty great idea, will do

Comment: @trichetriche atleast now you can remove downvote on my answer

Comment: @PardeepJain but while we're at best practices in SOF, you should remove your answer, as it is a duplicate of mine, and instead upvote mine. I don't mind if you do so, but if you want to be consistent, that should be your next move :)

Comment: @trichetriche cool, Done. I hope you dont mind I have edited your answer with some new content from my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I got my solution. @trichetriche

Comment: @PardeepJain No problem, maybe you should also edit to show how to use named contents in the component selector

Comment: @iamrajshah no problem, glad I could help !